# How make View in Yii and postgres Report By Month

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I'm newbie in Yii.
i want to ask,how to make a report in Yii with a view like this
[image: sample report]

sample data like this

```
  id  | vehicle_typeid |  spk_num  |     vin_num      | retail_date |  bpk_num  | sc_id | notes |   price   | dealer_senderid 
------+----------------+-----------+------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------------
  515 |            120 | CAR00003  | H4TB2H26CC000002 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00003  |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  516 |            120 | CAR00004  | H4TB2H26CC000003 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00004  |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  518 |            120 | CAR00006  | H4TB2H26CC000005 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00006  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  519 |            120 | CAR00007  | H4TB2H26CC000006 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00007  |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  520 |            120 | CAR00008  | H4TB2H26CC000007 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00008  |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  521 |            120 | CAR00009  | H4TB2H26CC000008 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00009  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  522 |            120 | CAR00010  | H4TB2H26CC000009 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00010  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  524 |            120 | CAR00012  | H4TB2H26CC000011 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00012  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  525 |            120 | CAR00013  | H4TB2H26CC000012 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00013  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  526 |            120 | CAR00014  | H4TB2H26CC000013 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00014  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  527 |            120 | CAR00015  | H4TB2H26CC000014 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00015  |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  528 |            120 | CAR00016  | H4TB2H26CC000015 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00016  |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  530 |            120 | CAR00018  | H4XZ2D26CC000002 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00018  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  531 |            120 | CAR00019  | H4XZ2D26CC000003 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00019  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  532 |            120 | CAR00020  | H4XZ2D26CC000004 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00020  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  533 |            120 | CAR00021  | H4XZ2D26CC000005 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00021  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  535 |            120 | CAR00023  | H4XZ2D26CC000007 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00023  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  536 |            120 | CAR00024  | H4XZ2D26CC000008 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00024  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  537 |            120 | CAR00025  | H4XZ2D26CC000009 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00025  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  538 |            120 | CAR00026  | H4AA5D26CC000001 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00026  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  539 |            120 | CAR00027  | H4AA5D26CC000002 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00027  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  541 |            120 | CAR00029  | H4AA5D26CC000004 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00029  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  542 |            120 | CAR00030  | H4AA5D26CC000005 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00030  |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  543 |            120 | CAR00031  | H4AA5D26CC000006 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00031  |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  544 |            120 | CAR00032  | H4AA5D26CC000007 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00032  |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  545 |            120 | CAR00033  | H4AA5D26CC000008 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00033  |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  547 |            120 | CAR00035  | H4AA5D26CC000010 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00035  |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
  548 |            120 | ADE00001  | H2AB3D27CC000001 | 2015-11-05  | ADE00001  |     5 |       | 500000000 | 831016307
  549 |            121 | ADE00002  | H2AB3D27CC000002 | 2015-11-05  | ADE00002  |     6 |       | 500000000 | 831016307
  550 |            121 | ADE00003  | H2AB3D27CC000003 | 2015-11-05  | ADE00003  |     7 |       | 500000000 | 831016307
  551 |            121 | ADE00004  | H2AB3D27CC000004 | 2015-11-05  | ADE00004  |     8 |       | 500000000 | 831016307
```

and this sample query with group by sc_id (sc_id is salesman)

```
starclub_new=> select sc_id,count(*) from sc_recsales group by sc_id;
 sc_id | count 
-------+-------
    14 |     5
    25 |    25
    27 |    22
     8 |    25
    12 |     8
    17 |     7
    28 |    28
     1 |    14
    15 |     9
    10 |     8
    26 |    25
    11 |    14
     4 |     4
    18 |     7
    30 |    26
    16 |     8
     6 |    25
    19 |     7
    29 |    23
     2 |    12
    21 |    23
     3 |     5
    23 |    25
    20 |    24
     5 |    26
    13 |     6
    22 |    23
     9 |    25
     7 |    25
    24 |    25
```

and this if i do this by query

```
 year | month | sc_id | entries 
------+-------+-------+---------
 2015 |    12 |    10 |       3
 2016 |     1 |    23 |       7
 2015 |    12 |     1 |      10
 2015 |    12 |    15 |       3
 2015 |    11 |     6 |       5
 2015 |    12 |     8 |      10
 2015 |    10 |    12 |       1
 2015 |    12 |    17 |       2
 2015 |    12 |    28 |      11
 2015 |    12 |    12 |       3
 2015 |    10 |     8 |       1
 2016 |     1 |     5 |      11
 2015 |    12 |    25 |       7
 2016 |     1 |    13 |       3
 2015 |    11 |    29 |       8
 2015 |    10 |    25 |       3
 2015 |    12 |    27 |      11
 2015 |    11 |    19 |       2
 2015 |    11 |     3 |       2
 2015 |    12 |    14 |       3
 2016 |     1 |     9 |      10
 2016 |     1 |    24 |       9
 2015 |    11 |     1 |       1
 2016 |     1 |     7 |       7
 2015 |    11 |    15 |       1
 2016 |     1 |    16 |       3
 2015 |    12 |     6 |      11
 2015 |    11 |     2 |       1
 2015 |    11 |    21 |       3
 2015 |    12 |    24 |      10
 2015 |    12 |     7 |      12
 2015 |    12 |    16 |       2
 2016 |     1 |     6 |       9
 2015 |    11 |    11 |       1
 2015 |    10 |    24 |       2
 2016 |     1 |    14 |       2
```

in model i create method for get all data with group by.

```
    public static function getTest() {
            $salesCount = ScRecsales::find()
                                ->select(['COUNT(*) as cnt, sc_id'])
                //              ->where('approved = 1')
                                //->groupBy(['sc_id', 'lead_type_id'])
                                ->groupBy(['sc_id'])
                                ->all();

            return $salesCount;
    }
```

and I am confused how to make in view. I am still learning programming :-(

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question? "how to make in view" - are trying to diplay the data in a view or do you want to create a view table?

Comment: I want to display data such as the image above

Comment: This is not a question. Start with reading this http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/

Answer (score 0):

The way I recommend is to use a widget provided by Yii. See the detailed tutorial about how to use one here:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets

You can use ListView or GridView, which is more suitable for you.

However, since your query will return an array of ActiveRecords populated by your data, there is still the old way to create a table for yourself by iterating through the array and printting out the data.